# how to program hex file of a NIOS II project addional in bitstream programming process?

Tags: c, fpga, intel-fpga, quartus, nios

I want to add the .hex output file of a simple NIOS II project into the download process of the bitstream in quartus. I already ​added the .qip file (necessary for memory initialization) to my quartus project. But the software isn't processed after programming. Programming and running the software via JTAG-UART works.

I am using the Quartus Prime Lite Edtion 18.0. with the DEO-NANO development board (CYCLONE IV EP4CE22F17C6N as on board FPGA).

So what can be the reason for my problem? What do I have to add in my development process? What do I forget?

Best regards Florian

Comment: point "Add Hex File to Project" of http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/fpgas/alteraHowTos/simpleNiosII.html ?

Comment: I already tried to additionally adding the related hex file to the project. But it doesn't change the behavior. So what else could be the problem?